# mdframed in lists

Tags: lists, mdframed

I am using a frame environment defined with `mdframed` to write annotations in my documents.
When I use this environment as the first thing after a `\label` in a list, the following happens:

[image]

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xcolor]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[hidealllines=true, backgroundcolor=gray!30]{env}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item text

    \item \begin{env}
        foo
    \end{env}

    \item more text

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The Space before list element 2 is missing and its label is misaligned.

Can this be prevented?

Comment: Add `\leavevmode` just before `\begin{env}`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: If I do that, there is an empty line behind the list label and the frame is pushed below it. Can this be avoided?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I present three options:

1. Use `\leavevmode` before beginning the environment. This, however will force the framed box to appear below the item and you might then need to manually fix the position of required.
2. If no page breaks will occur inside the box, surround it with a `\parbox` of width equal to `\linewidth`.
3. Switch to the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package which will give you what you want without further adjustments.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xcolor,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newmdenv[hidealllines=true, backgroundcolor=gray!30]{env}
\newtcolorbox{envA}[1][]{colback=gray!30,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\item \leavevmode\begin{env}
foo
\end{env}
\item \parbox{\linewidth}{\begin{env}
bar
\end{env}}
\item more text
\item \begin{envA}
foo
\end{envA}
\item more text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]